# Inline templating does not work along with modularity?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, modular-design

I'm making a modular application:

> main.rb

```
require "sinatra/namespace"
require "haml"
Dir.glob("servers/*/server.rb").each do |server|
  require_relative server
end
```

And I want to do inline templating:

> servers/some/server.rb

```
namespace "/some/hello" do
  get "/" do
    haml :index
  end
end

__END__

@@ index
!!!
%html
  hello
```

But I get the:

> No such file or directory - views/index.haml

It works if I move the template to main.rb but then it's kinda not modular anymore.

Comment: the note [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Inline%20Templates) seems applicable.  You're requiring sinatra in a different file right?

Comment: @Anthony, I put `enable :inline_templates` in main.rb (before requiring modules) but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error in another case:

> main.rb

```
require_relative "server_common"

get / do
  haml :index
end

__END__

@@ index
!!!
.....
```

> server_common.rb

```
require "sinatra"
.....
```

**Solution:**

```
require "sinatra"
set :inline_templates, caller.first[/[^:]+/]
```

Also had to add this because Sinatra didn't autorun.

```
set :app_file, caller.first[/[^:]+/]
```